# Inserting and removing table element in Lua

Tags: lua

I don't understand why the following code produces error.

The code begins with the `main()` function at the bottom.

```
heads = {}
function push(t)
    if (#t == 2) then
        table.insert(heads, t)
    end
end
function remove(id)
    for i = 1, #heads do
        if (heads[i][2] == id) then
            table.remove(heads, i)
        end
    end
end
function main()
    push({50, 1})
    push({50, 2})
    push({50, 3})
    remove(2)
end
```

When I run the code, I get `attempt to index a nil value (field '?')` error.

I expect to push the subtable elements into the table and then remove only the second one. So the resulting elements can be `{50, 1}` and `{50, 3}`.

Why is my code not working and how to fix this?

Comment: Andrew got it right. Never try to remove a value inside a table when you iterate the table. This is a common issue in many languages. Usually, you would store the index first and then remove the element after the loop. However, what you try to do is slow. Why not simply using the id as key in your table?

Comment: @modiX Could you please show me how to do it? I'm a newbie.

Comment: Simply use heads[id] = element to add a new element and heads[id] = nil to remove the element with the given ID again. No need for any slow function calls and iterations.

Comment: @modiX First you have to decide if the table has a [sequence](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7) and should always have a sequence. Your method potentially leaves the table not having a sequence.

Comment: @TomBlodget True, the insert sequence would be lost. If this should be preserved it might be clever to maintain an id->i lookup table to be able to optain or remove elements without iterations on the table itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew got it right. Never try to remove a value inside a table when you iterate the table. This is a common issue in many languages. Usually, you would store the value first and then remove like so:

```
local e
for i = 1, #heads do
    if (heads[i][2] == id) then
        e = i
        break
    end
end
if e then table.remove(heads, e) end
```

However, this solution is slow. Simply use the ID as key of your table:

```
local heads = {}

heads[1] = 50 -- push
heads[2] = 50
heads[3] = 50
heads[2] = nil -- remove
```

No need for unnecessary function calls and iterations.

Comment: For efficiency you would want to break the loop once you found the element.
ByeBye

Answer (score 2):

According to 5.1 manual table.remove "Removes from table the element at position, shifting down other elements to close the space, if necessary"

size of heads (#heads) is calculated once before loop execution, when i==2 you call table.remove, and so size of the table shrinks to 2, and on next iteration you try index heads[3][2], but heads[3] is nil, therefore "attempt to index a nil value" error message.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew mentioned, `for i = 1, #heads do` will go to the *original* length of the list; if you shorten `heads` during the loop, then the final iteration(s) will read `heads[i]` and find only `nil`.

A simple way to fix this is to move *backwards* through the list, since removing an element only affects indices *after* the index you have removed from:

```
for i = #heads, 1, -1 do
    if heads[i][2] == id then
        table.remove(heads, i)
    end
end
```

Note that in any case, this is `O(n*d)` complexity and could be very slow if you are deleting many elements from the list. And, as others pointed out, there's a `O(1)` approach where you use a map from `v[1]` => `v` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid problems caused by removing fields while iterating over an array, I've used a `while` loop with an index variable, which is incremented at the end of each iteration, but decremented when an index is removed. So, for instance, to remove all elements with an even index:

```
local t = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
local i = 1
while t[i] do
  if t[i] % 2 == 0 then
    table.remove(t, i)
    i = i - 1
  end
  i = i + 1
end
```

This method allows you to iterate over array indices in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing this iteration, in case of many items that are to be removed, I'd rather go for

```lua
local result = {}
for _, v in ipairs(myTab) do
  if v == 'nice' then
    table.insert(result, v)
  end
end
myTab = result
```

as `table.remove` is slow when shifting many elements.